# NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'dlongitude' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter. I was trying to make a common class and access its variables from other classes. I have this class in my app:

```
class Target {
  double dlatitude;
  double dlongitude;
  Target({this.dlatitude, this.dlongitude});
}
```

I am using this class in other stateful widgets to set the value of its variable as this:

```
class _EditLocationState extends State<EditLocation> {
  final TextEditingController _search = TextEditingController();

  Target target = Target();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _search.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: 20,
            top: 50,
            right: 20,
            child: TextField(
              controller: _search,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.grey[400],
                hintText: "${widget.location}",
                ),
              ),
            ),
            
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          var array = _search.text.split(",");
            Target(
                dlongitude: double.parse(array[0]),
                dlatitude: double.parse(array[1]));
          }
          print(target.dlatitude); // null value is printed here.
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.done),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And whenever I am trying to access Target variables values in other Widgets I am getting this error: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'dlongitude' was called on null.

```
class _SearchRideState extends State<SearchRide> {
  final TextEditingController _search = TextEditingController();

  Target target=Target();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _search.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: 20,
            top: 50,
            right: 20,
            child: TextField(
              controller: _search,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.grey[400],
                hintText: "${target.dlatitude},${target.dlongitude}"
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have to refer [class](https://dart.dev/samples#classes) and [tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour).

Now coming to your question, If you are working with the class and want to assign the value it will be done like this:

```
Target target = Target(dlatitude: 1.1, dlongitude: 2.0);
```

You just did `Target target = Target();` that's why the empty object is created as well as you got a null value there. And the below code is meaning less.

```
onPressed: () {
  var array = _search.text.split(",");
  Target(
    dlongitude: double.parse(array[0]),
    dlatitude: double.parse(array[1]),
  );
  print(target.dlatitude);
}
```

1.That's why the solution for your code is as below:
Remove `Target target = Target();`

```
onPressed: () {
  var array = _search.text.split(",");
  Target target = Target(
    dlongitude: double.parse(array[0]),
    dlatitude: double.parse(array[1]),
  );
  print(target.dlatitude);
}
```

2.Or you can provide a default value in class:

```
class Target {
  double dlatitude;
  double dlongitude;
  Target({this.dlatitude=0.0, this.dlongitude=0.0});
}
```

And then in your logic, it will be like:

The `Target target = Target();` code is remain as it is. And

```
onPressed: () {
  var array = _search.text.split(",");
  target.dlongitud = double.parse(array[0]);
  target.dlongitude = double.parse(array[1]);
  print(target.dlatitude);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using optional parameters which means that if they are not passed to the constructor like you do in your example:

```
Target target=Target();
```

the default value of its attributes is null thus the 'error: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'dlongitude' '.

You can do 2 things about that:

1. Actually assigning a value to the attributes as `var target=Target(dlatitude:0.0, dlongitude:4.5);`

2.Or defining a default value to the attributes so they can never be null

```
class Target {
  double dlatitude;
  double dlongitude;
  Target({this.dlatitude=0.0, this.dlongitude=0.0});
}
```

I recommend you to take the language [tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) it is really well written.